# "TestFlight Users In The Provisioning Profile" doesn't coincide with users in the AdHoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight

I have created a totally new TestFlight account, when I add the build to the account I see 79 users under `TestFlight Users In The Provisioning Profile`. The problem is that I have built the application using an ADHoc provisioning profile that contains just 3 devices, so why I'm seeing the full list of devices that I've registered with the Apple Developer Portal and not just the device that are available in the Provisioning profile (as stated by the sentence `TestFlight Users In The Provisioning Profile`) ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share user information. But is extremely simple... there are 79 user under the `TestFlight Users In The Provisioning Profile` list while they should be just 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I occasionally run into this problem and get it working again after trying a few things.

1. Restart Xcode. (It's amazing how often that solves the problem.)
2. Make sure that you are bundling the correct provisioning profile with the app when archiving and exporting. If you're using Xcode 6, the process has been changed a bit and you might be including the wrong profile. (Look in your Build Settings and then also look at the details on each screen as you are exporting the archive.)
3. Try re-generating your provisioning profile.
4. Make sure you have refreshed your account in Xcode so that it has the latest provisioning profile.
5. If those don't work, try creating a new signing certificate and generating your profile with that.
6. Then refresh your account in Xcode again.
7. If that's still not working, try removing your account from Xcode completely, restarting Xcode, and adding your account again.

Those are some of the tricks I use to get things working again. Maybe there is a more definitive answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same problem.
This is because the provisioning profile you create from apple developer account.
Have that 79 devices register with that apple developer account.
Please check that account once.